# Power series with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n$ where we have

Tags: integration

$a_n+Aa_{n-1}+Ba_{n-2}=0$ with $n=2,3,...$ we have to prove that for all $x$ for which the series converges its sum is $\frac{a_0+(a_1+Aa_0)x}{1+Ax+Bx^2}$.  I develop the prove and effectively reach $(1+Ax+Bx^2) \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=a_0+(a_1+Aa_0)x$ and then I have to see that $1+Ax+Bx^2$ is not zero, here is the problem I don't know how can I prove this, I think that I need more hypothesis to be able to prove this part, but the exercise does not give them.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z$ be a point where the series converges, and let $s := \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ denote its sum.
You have that
$$
0 = \sum_{n=2}^\infty (a_n + A a_{n-1} + B a_{n-2}) z^n
= \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n z^n + Az \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k z^k + B z^2 \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^j
$$
(with $k = n-1$ and $j = n-2$), hence
$$
0 = (s - a_0 - a_1 z) + Az(s - a_0) + Bz^2 s,
$$
so that
$$
s = \frac{a_0 + (a_1 + a_0 A) z}{1 + Az + B z^2}.
$$